# Prove that $A$ is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ $X(A)$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

**Let:**

- $I(p,q)$ - closed segment with ends $p,q\in \mathbb R^3$
- $A\subset (0,1)\subset \mathbb R$
- $X(A)=\bigcup \{I \Big( (x,0,\tan x),(x,x^3,0) \Big):x\in A \} \subset \mathbb R^3$ with the Euclidean metric

**Prove that:** subset $A$ of segment $(0,1)$ with Euclidean topology is compact $\Leftrightarrow$ $X(A)$ is compact in the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$

**My attempts:**

**1)** $A$ is compact $\Rightarrow$ $X(A)$ is compact

We know that closed segment $I(p,q)$ can write by definition as $I(p,q)=\big\{t\cdot p+(1-t)\cdot q\ \big|\ t\in[0,1]\big\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$. Let: $v(x)=(x,0,\tan x)
$, $w(x)=(x,x^3,0)$. Of course functions $v,w$ are continuous for $x\in (0,1)$. This implies that $X(A)$ is a continuous image of $A\times [0,1]$ via $(x,t)\mapsto t\cdot v(x)+(1-t)\cdot w(x)$.
 Since $A$ is compact then $A\times [0,1]$ is compact too (by Tychonoff's theorem, the cartesian product of compact spaces is compact). So $X(A)$ compact as an image of a compact set by continuous mapping.

**My questions:**

Firstly, I am not sure my proof "$A$ is compact $\Rightarrow$ $X(A)$ is compact" is correct so I would be grateful if you could comment on it. Secondly, I have no idea how to prove the implication: $A$ is compact $\Leftarrow$ $X(A)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. For the converse consider the projection map $p : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R, p(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1$. This is continuous and $p(X(A)) = A$. Note that the first coodinate of $tv(x) + (1-t)w(x) \in A(X)$ is $x$.

Also observe that your map $F: A \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R^3, F(x,t) = tv(x) +(1-t)w(x)$, is an embedding because it is clearly injective and $A \times [0,1]$ is compact. This means that $A \times [0,1] \approx X(A)$.

Comment: Very clear solution, thank you very much!